# How long does Sonatype staging take to sync my artifacts with Maven central

Tags: maven, nexus, sonatype

I have successfully deployed my Maven artifacts (release) into Sonatype's staging repository with Maven.

Uploading address is https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/

I would like to know how long will it take before I can see them in the central repository?

Answer (score 67):

Provided you have followed the steps to activate the sync, it should take [about 2 hours](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide#SonatypeOSSMavenRepositoryUsageGuide-9.ActivateCentralSync).

> 9 Activate Central Sync
>
> The first time you promote a release, you need to comment on the OSSRH JIRA ticket you created in Section 3 so we can know you are ready to be synced. We will review your promoted artifacts. If no problem found, we will activate Central Sync for you and close your JIRA ticket.
>
> After Central Sync is activated, your future promotion will be synced automatically. The sync process runs roughly every 2 hours.

Comment: Yes, I see, Thanks! And I want to know how long the Sonatype engineers will read my comment and approve my artifacts?

Comment: More documentation about Central is now available at http://central.sonatype.org including help related links at http://central.sonatype.org/pages/help.html and the migrated and updated guide for ossrh http://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html and lots more details.

Comment: Also keep in mind that you need to release the artifacts before they get synced. More at http://central.sonatype.org/pages/releasing-the-deployment.html

Comment: [This page](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html#releasing-to-central) currently claims synch to Central after release takes about ten minutes.

Comment: For clarification it takes roughly 10 minutes for your artefacts to become available within central, though they will not appear in central search results at [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org) for up to two hours. What this means for you is that you can refer to the dependencies after 10 minutes but you can't see them for two hours in central.

Comment: "We will review your promoted artifacts. If no problem found, we will activate Central Sync for you and close your JIRA ticket."  This appears to no longer be required.  They closed my ticket without it, and the docs no longer have this as a step.

Answer (score 22):

After a successful release the artifact will be published to Central, typically within 10 minutes. However updates to search.maven.org can take up to two hours.

Comment: For further visitors, [Releasing to Central](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html#releasing-to-central)

Comment: so how come i do see my artifact in OSS Nexus https://oss.sonatype.org/#welcome (under Releases), but i still cannot see it in Central? (12 hours passed!)?

Comment: it took much more than expected, but eventually it appeared in Maven Central :)

Comment: There were cases that happened almost instantly, and other cases where it took couple of hours.

Answer (score 11):

From my last experience, the artifact that I released, it was synced with the Central Repository in ~8 hours.

Answer (score 9):

In case others are seeing this question, here's an excerpt from the email received by Central OSSRH (Sonatype) after releasing the first artifact for a new project:

> Central sync is activated for your.domain.artifact. After you successfully release, your component will be published to Central **https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/, typically within 30 minutes**, though updates to **https://search.maven.org can take up to four hours**.

Comment: The mail itself can land in your inbox ~ten minutes after _releasing_ the staging repository. However when I received the mail the sync was already done visible on repo1.